# How to make the GridView center of the device?

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/homeGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="200dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vertical_space" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to make the GridView center of the device?

Comment: I can see android:layout_gravity="center" and android:gravity="center" is already added to the view. what is the output you get on the screen? have you tried android:horizontalSpacing ?

Comment: If you can, provide us a screenshot of your layout with data/image.

Comment: @JaAd: Can you look on this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570372/making-the-gridview-center-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use **Relative Layout** instead of Linear Layout and apply **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** in your Gird View

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set your Gridview's `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to wrap_content?